# Boot-repair does not open

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, boot-repair

Im currently trying to get windows to start so i can play "osu!" but after installing xubuntu along side Windows, Windows no longer boots. In the grub menu i get an option called "Windows boot loader" ( or something like that) but when i click it, i just get a black screen, and i don't think it will ever change because i left it like that for a while and it never started it. So i found out about boot-repair and when i tried to install it everything i think went fine aside from the last part.

> /usr/sbin/boot-repair-bin: line 18: /usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd.sh: No such file or directory
>   /usr/sbin/boot-repair-bin: line 19: cmd_start: command not found

Im still very new and i dont really know what to do to fix it
I could share all of what happend before if that is what someone would like me to do but this was the part that stuck out the most, i believe everything else was fine. 
Also im running a dell that came with windows 8 already installed if that effects anything, and i installed xubuntu from a flash drive.

Comment: If your Dell had Windows 8, then it is UEFI. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? And are you adding Boot-Repair to the Ubuntu live installer flash drive using ppa? The ISO is now rather old. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: When i try to run boot-Info i get:
/usr/sbin/boot-info-bin: line 18: /usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/boot-info-bin: line 19: cmd_start: command not found

Comment: From what verison of Ubuntu are you running the Boot-Repair?

Answer (score 2):

I recently upgraded my Windows and found my grub menu missing, which was stopping me from getting into my linux. I somehow found a way to get into my Ubuntu (17.04) and tried boot repair, but got the same error:

```
/usr/sbin/boot-repair-bin: line 18: /usr/share/boot-sav/bs-cmd.sh: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/boot-repair-bin: line 19: cmd_start: command not found
```

After sometime my software updater suggested me a few more updates that were kind of dependencies to the boot repair I just installed. In case you didn't get it, do run these commands once:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you have already done the first three steps, then `sudo apt-get upgrade` should help.

Comment: Yeah i tried to and i got the same error. I ended up giving up to try to do it from My installed system and  a i just used Ubuntu live and then tried to run boot-repair, it worked.

Comment: Yeah that's an alternate way to do it and suggested on many websites. My only point being, you need to upgrade once again after you've installed boot repair without which you'll not get the required softwares and hence not be able to run boot repair.

Comment: This worked for me after I also installed glade2script-python3 (with `sudo apt-get install glade2script-python3`)